# How to detect a click from a shadow dom element?

Tags: html, google-chrome, shadow-dom

For example, when user clicks on the controls of a video tag.
I have searched the internet and have found nothing.

Comment: When a user clicks on a video control, the `<video>` element fires an equivalent event which you can listen to. For example, see [Essential Audio and Video Events for HTML5](http://www.sitepoint.com/essential-audio-and-video-events-for-html5/)

Comment: This is kind of dirty hack. I don't want to use it.

Comment: How is the standard HTML5 video API a hack?

Comment: I didn't say the api is a hack. I meant method you suggest.

Comment: Detecting button clicks is always done through event listeners (`button.addEventListener('click',function(e){});`). Now you're just listening for a custom event (`playButton.addEventListener('play',function(e){};`).